# AttributeError: 'SimpleImputer' object has no attribute '_validate_data' in PyCaret

Tags: python, scikit-learn, pycaret

I am using PyCaret and get an error.

```
AttributeError: 'SimpleImputer' object has no attribute '_validate_data'
```

Trying to create a basic instance.

```
# Create a basic PyCaret instance
import pycaret
from pycaret.regression import *
mlb_pycaret = setup(data = pycaret_df, target = 'pts', train_size = 0.8, numeric_features = ['home', 
'first_time_pitcher'], session_id = 123)
```

All my variables are numeric (I coerced two of them, which are boolean). My target variable is `label` and this is by default.

I also installed `PyCaret`, imported its regression, and re-installed `scikit learn`, imported `SimpleImputer` as `from sklearn.impute import SimpleImputer`

```
OBP_avg Numeric
SLG_avg Numeric
SB_avg  Numeric
RBI_avg Numeric
R_avg   Numeric
home    Numeric
first_time_pitcher  Numeric
park_ratio_OBP  Numeric
park_ratio_SLG  Numeric
SO_avg_p    Numeric
pts_500_parkadj_p   Numeric
pts_500_parkadj Numeric
SLG_avg_parkadj Numeric
OPS_avg_parkadj Numeric
SLG_avg_parkadj_p   Numeric
OPS_avg_parkadj_p   Numeric
pts_BxP Numeric
SLG_BxP Numeric
OPS_BxP Numeric
whip_SO_BxP Numeric
whip_SO_B   Numeric
whip_SO_B_parkadj   Numeric
order   Numeric
ops x pts_500 order15   Numeric
ops x pts_500 parkadj   Numeric
ops23 x pts_500 Numeric
ops x pts_500 orderadj  Numeric
whip_p  Numeric
whip_SO_p   Numeric
whip_SO_parkadj_p   Numeric
whip_parkadj_p  Numeric
pts Label
```

My traceback is the following:

[image]

Comment: Why did you import `pycaret` first and what version of `scikit-learn` is being used by the environment?  Have you tried skipping the `numeric_features` parameter? What about trying the `numeric_iterative_imputer` and `numeric_imputation` parameters?

Comment: @MarkMoretto, I tried to skip `numeric_features`. It does not help. I have the same error, but with a much longer traceback. I intentionally imported `pycaret` and its regression right above the code, because in the past order mattered too. If I skip numeric features, `home` is treated as categorical and that second variable does not have class at all. I am not sure why `pts` is a `label`, because I am not doing classification (maybe it is fine). Parameters you mentioned are in `clustering` for PyCaret, I am not sure it will help here.

Comment: @MarkMoretto, I dropped half of variables with high correlation and everything worked perfectly. What happened? No clue.

Comment: Sweet! I was curious whether it would be a version issue since my installation also didn't have that function.  But, I'm glad to hear you got it working!

Comment: Likely wrong version of sklearn. It should be 0.23.2 right now and not 0.24 (6/2021).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The problem here is with the imputation. The default per [pycaret documentation](https://pycaret.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/regression.html) is 'simple' but in this case, you need to make that `imputation_type='iterative'` for it to work.

Comment: This works, but it may also be that your version of sklearn is wrong. As of 6/2021 it should be version 0.23.2, not the 0.24 version. Using 0.24 at this time will cause the same error.

Comment: I changed like you said, but now I got another problem: `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sklearn.kernel_ridge'`

Answer (score 1):

It's incompatibility of library, install pycaret again with: pip install pycaret pandas shap

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

Good day all. What helped me is installing pycaret=='2.3.10 ' and scikit-learn='0.23.2' at the same time. These two version are compatible and all works fine. I installed scikit-learn using conda as the older versions are not available through pip, and I installed Pycaret using pip3. I hope this helps all who have struggled to get this working like I did.

Comment: This is the answer for me.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what worked for me on this error:

go to line 568 in your base file here: C:\Users\Eric.conda\envs\AUTOGLUON\lib\site-packages\sklearn\impute_base.py then search for the following line of code:

"if self.strategy == "constant" or self.keep_empty_features:"

Perform the following change, then save the file:

## Change this:

```
    if self.strategy == "constant" or self.keep_empty_features:
        valid_statistics = statistics
        valid_statistics_indexes = None
```

## To this:

```
    if self.strategy == "constant" or (hasattr(self, 'keep_empty_features') and self.keep_empty_features):
        valid_statistics = statistics
        valid_statistics_indexes = None
```

Save changes. Then, restart the Python kernel for the notebook, and run the code again. It should now work.... Or at least I hope it does for you