# AttributeError: 'Simple_Imputer' object has no attribute 'fill_value_categorical'' in PyCaret

Tags: python, machine-learning, kaggle, pycaret

**I am using PyCaret and get an error.**

`AttributeError: 'Simple_Imputer' object has no attribute 'fill_value_categorical'`

**Trying to create a basic instance.**

```
!pip install pycaret==1.0

from pycaret.regression import *
exp_reg = setup(data=df, target='Survived', session_id=2)
```

Comment: Does it help https://stackoverflow.com/q/65012601#answers ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [AttributeError: 'SimpleImputer' object has no attribute '\_validate\_data' in PyCaret](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65012601/attributeerror-simpleimputer-object-has-no-attribute-validate-data-in-pyca)

Answer (score 2):

[@eddygeek's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70560862/14333696) is correct. I faced the same error, and forcing the installation of scikit-learn 0.23.2 did the trick.

```
pip install scikit-learn==0.23.2 --force-reinstall
```

Answer (score 1):

i reinstaled pycraret (`!pip install pycaret`) and it worked; no clue what happened.

Comment: There was installed (updatet) a library which PyCaret uses.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this error when I installed `pycaret` without its dependencies.

The following would cause this error:

```
!pip install imblearn --no-deps pycaret scikit-plot pyod lightgbm plotly
```

To avoid this error, change to:

```
!pip install pycaret
```

Answer (score 0):

- pycaret <= 2.3.5 requires sklearn == 0.23.2
- now pycaret has added a check in `setup` to fail early if sklearn version is wrong.
- issue of OP is because sklearn (presumably 0.24.x) introduced a new way to introspect `BaseEstimator` objects based on `__init__` signature (see [_get_param_names](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/d180184/sklearn/base.py#L165)), which requires than any `__init__` param has a corresponding class attribute of the same name. pycaret subclasses like `Simple_Imputer` currently does not conform to this expectation