# Installation always stuck on PyCaret 2.2.2 + Package problems

Tags: python, scikit-learn, anaconda, jupyter, pycaret

I'm stuck on an issue that I can't seem to solve. I was fine using PyCaret on my other PC and had recently got a new desktop.

I was working on one dataset on my old PC and had no problems with `setup()` and PyCaret preprocessed my data without any issues. When I worked on my the **same dataset** with my new desktop and Jupyter newly installed, I noticed I ran into an `ValueError: Setting a random_state has no effect since shuffle is False. You should leave random_state to its default (None), or set shuffle=True.` I thought it was strange but went on to set `fold_shuffle=True` to get through this.

Next, I encountered `AttributeError: 'Simple_Imputer' object has no attribute 'fill_value_categorical'`. It seems I'm getting failures at every step of setup(). I went through the forums and found a [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67678545/attributeerror-simple-imputer-object-has-no-attribute-fill-value-categorical) where at the bottom of it, @eddygeek mentioned that PyCaret was set up to fail if the sklearn version is wrong. **This got me looking into the packages I have that may meet dependencies between packages.**

I noticed the following issues:

1. I get several errors:
   `ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: C:\Users\%%USER%%\anaconda3\python.exe'`
   `Ignoring numpy: markers 'python_version >= "3.8" and platform_system == "AIX"' don't match your environment`
   `ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement scikit-learn==0.23.2`
   [Screenshot of more errors attached](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dXbQK.png)
2. Jupyter Notebook fails to launch because of `Pandas Profiling Import Error: cannot import name 'soft_unicode' from 'markupsafe'`. I got around this by installing `markupsafe===2.0.1` but this leads to incompatibility warning by pandas-profiling 3.2.0 saying it needs markupsafe 2.1.1
3. PyCaret keeps getting installed as 2.2.2 version. I think that's why it keeps looking for scikit-learn 0.23.2 when the latest PyCaret 2.3.10 works with scikit-learn >=1.0. I've tried uninstalling and reinstalling PyCaret several times but it's still the same.

**What I've done**

I'm on Python 3.9.12 that was installed together with Anaconda3. My PyCaret was installed with `pip install pycaret[full] --user` on Anaconda Prompt.

In my `pip list`, I have:

- scikit-learn 1.1.2
- markupsafe 2.1.1
- pandas-profiling 3.2.0
- pycaret 2.2.2

I've added `C:\Users\%%USER%%\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\Scripts` to PATH

I'm really at my wits end so I hope I can get some advice on this. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I've encountered the very same issues and solved as follows.

According to the [documentation](https://pycaret.gitbook.io/docs/get-started/installation), there are a few problems with your setup:

1. PyCaret is not yet compatible with `sklearn>=0.23.2`
2. PyCaret is tested and supported on the following 64-bit systems:

   Python 3.6 – 3.8
   Python 3.9 for Ubuntu only

So if you're using python 3.9 on Windows, I'd start with that.

I went into a rabbit hole of downgrading the packages and getting one error after another.

Long story short, the setup that finally worked was:

```
sklearn 0.23.1
scipy 1.5.2
```

Both installed on a **virtual conda environment** but at the end I had to run:

```
pip3 install pycaret[full]
```

Notice `pip3` intead of `pip` because I was getting permission errors.

Answer (score 0):

You are using a very old version of pycaret which does not work in Python 3.9. Please install the latest version in a fresh (conda) environment. Make sure it is a new environment in order to avoid any package issues.

```bash
# This installs the pre-release 3.0.0 release which has reduced dependencies.
pip install --pre pycaret
```

Comment: It wasn't my choice to install it as 2.2.2. If you see my Point 3, it keeps getting installed as 2.2.2 even though I've tried pip install pycaret [full]. But I'll try out 3.0.0