# Pycaret - 'Make_Time_Features' object has no attribute 'list_of_features'

Tags: scikit-learn, pycaret

I am trying to create a model using pycaret just as:

```
from pycaret.classification import *

clf1 = setup(data = dt, target = 'group')
lr = create_model('lr')
```

Then I get:

```
AttributeError: 'Simple_Imputer' object has no attribute 'fill_value_categorical'
```

So, following [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65012601/attributeerror-simpleimputer-object-has-no-attribute-validate-data-in-pyca), I added:

```
clf1 = setup(data = dt, target = 'group',  imputation_type='iterative' )
lr = create_model('lr')
```

Then I get:

```
AttributeError: 'Make_Time_Features' object has no attribute 'list_of_features'
```

My version of sklearn is 0.23.2 and pycaret is 2.3.2

Comment: Please add the specifics of your dataset (shape, data types, missing values, etc.) and preferably a small sample so that this issue can be reproduced by others (see [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example))

Comment: I'm having the same issue with macOS. I will try now `pip install pycaret --force-reinstall`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You mentioned my previous question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65012601/attributeerror-simpleimputer-object-has-no-attribute-validate-data-in-pyca).

I just faced the same issue as you on Colab. It is 100% issue with libraries.

Initially, I got the error for `SMOTE`:

- `AttributeError: 'SMOTE' object has no attribute '_validate_data'

After installing/reinstalling libraries I got exactly your error.

How did I resolve it?

- Started to run Colab and imported all common libraries (`pd`, `np`, `scikit`, etc).
- Installed PyCaret via `pip install`. Then `import pycaret` and `from pycaret.classification import *`
- Colab reacted: you have issues with `scipy`, `sklearn`, `lightgbm`, please restart your runtime.
- Restarted my runtime on Colab
- Imported all libraries again as I did in step 1
- Ran `import pycaret` and `from pycaret.classification import *` only

My final code:

```
# Initialize the setup with SMOTE
clf_smote = setup(
    data,
    session_id = 123,
    target = 'Target',
    remove_multicollinearity = True,
    multicollinearity_threshold = 0.95, 
    fix_imbalance = True
)
```

I did not use `imputation_type='iterative'` as in my question above.

Proof of running:

[image]

It worked, but it was my solution. Would be great to have a more detailed guide on how to deal with such issues, using this amazing library.

Answer (score 2):

Interestingly for me `pip install scikit-learn==0.23.2` did the trick. It was the version.